# How to mock StatusBarManager.getHeight in Jest test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, expo

I'm using expo 34 and [react-native-ui-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ui-lib) from wix and have a problem to setup jest tests for my components. The problem looks to appear in [link](https://github.com/wix/react-native-ui-lib/blob/2ea0ae040c2abfd937cfc44a6ef0990be19ac922/src/helpers/Constants.js#L26) of the wix library

```
function setStatusBarHeight() {
  statusBarHeight = isIOS ? 20 : StatusBarManager.HEIGHT;
  if (isIOS) {
    // override guesstimate height with the actual height from StatusBarManager
    StatusBarManager.getHeight(data => (statusBarHeight = data.height));
  }
}
```

TypeError: StatusBarManager.getHeight is not a function

> TypeError: StatusBarManager.getHeight is not a function
>   If I simply change it and return 42 my test can run.

Is it any way to mock `StatusBarManager.getHeight` in jest?

I've tried to create `jest-setup.js` in my root folder

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

NativeModules.StatusBarManager = {getHeight: jest.fn()};

// mock native modules
jest.mock('@react-native-community/blur', () => {});
```

But it didn't work. 
My current `jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    preset: "jest-expo",
    moduleFileExtensions: ['js','jsx','json', 'ts', 'tsx'],
    transform: {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "babel-jest"
    },
    testMatch: [
      "**/*.test.ts?(x)"
    ],
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem with this code

```
import React from 'react'
import 'react-native'
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native' // !this module
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import Description from './Description'

// and this mock
NativeModules.StatusBarManager = {getHeight: jest.fn()}

describe('TextArea test', () => {
  it('Empty TextArea with title', () => {
    const description = renderer.create(
    <Description {...{
```