# TypeError: StatusBarManager.getHeight is not a function

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I was trying to use `react-native-ui-lib` and `jest` in a project, however, when starting to test, it returns an error saying

> TypeError: StatusBarManager.getHeight is not a function.

I did a research and tried to add `transformIgnorePatterns` in my *package.json* but it didn't work.

Here is part of my **package.json**:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.3.3",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.57.63",
    "babel-jest": "24.8.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
    "tslint": "^5.17.0",
    "tslint-config-airbnb": "^5.11.1",
    "tslint-react": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(react-native|native-base|react-native-ui-lib|react-native-navigation|react-native-vector-icons|@react-native-community|react-native-pin-view|react-native-version-number|react-native-config|react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view|react-native-iphone-x-helper|react-native-camera|react-native-barcode-mask|react-native-elements|react-native-status-bar-height|react-native-ratings)/)"
    ]
  }
```

I am using **react-native @0.59.9** and **react-native-ui-lib ^3.37.0**.

Screenshot of error image link:

[image]

Comment: You need to mock StatusBarManager. Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57755131/how-to-mock-statusbarmanager-getheight-in-jest-test

Comment: Worked well, thanks!

Comment: Please add your code in your question.